# How is Jam factor calculated?

Tags: routes, here-api, traffic

I am still reading the documentation about [TravelTimeSection](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic-data-service/dev_guide/topics-api/definitions-traveltimesection.html) and found only this [Acronyms](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/common-acronyms.html). I am interested in Jam Factor, but there is limited information.
It would help a lot if you could provide more information about jam factor. I need more details about how is it computed (formula), which are units of measurement and anything else that you provide to make it clear about this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There's no unit of measurement. As you've read in the documentation you've found, Jam Factor is simply a number between 0.0 and 10.0 (and -1 too).

Regarding how this is calculated, I guess this is an information that HERE wouldn't want to share with you, but you could try asking them directly through their customer service or https://heredev.slack.com/

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the `jamFactor` can be interpreted like this:

- 0 <= `jamFactor` < 4: No or light traffic.
- 4 <= `jamFactor` < 8: Moderate or slow traffic.
- 8 <= `jamFactor` < 10: Severe traffic.
- `jamFactor` = 10: No traffic, ie. the road is blocked.

Note that the `jamFactor` is *not* necessarily a linear result calculated from the ratio of `trafficSpeedInMetersPerSecond` / `baseSpeedInMetersPerSecond`as it additionally takes also the road type and other conditions into account.

This info is taken from the documentation for the [HERE SDK for Android (Navigate Edition)](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.6.2.0/dev_guide/topics/routing.html#find-traffic-along-a-route). It should be similar for other HERE APIs / products.